# Configure apache for Ruby CGI

Tags: ruby, apache

I've been struggling for configuring apache so that my ruby cgi
script can be executed. I tried the following in httpd.conf

1. `LoadModule cgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_cgi.so`
2. `ScriptAliasMatch "/cgi-bin/" "/mydirectory/cgi-bin/"`
3. `<Directory "/mydirectory/cgi-bin">
       AllowOverride All
       Options ExecCGI
       AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .rb
       Require all granted
   </Directory>`
4. set mycgi.rb permission to be executable

But no matter how I tried, just cannot get my mycgi.rb to execute.
I tried different combination in httpd.conf, sometimes I got permission denied (which is the closest I can get:), sometimes I got internal server error.

ALso, sometimes the server is trying to load mycgi.rb/index.html,
which it was taking my mycgi.rb as a directory.

What else do I need to do to make it work? (I checked some previous
similar posts, but none of them works for me)

Comment: Whenever you get an error, that's progress - check your Apache's `error_log` (typically at `/var/log/apache2`). If you can't figure the errors out, please post the the relevant lines from the log.

Comment: Thank you very much. I checked. error_log is really helpful.